# Google ReCaptcha 2 cuts off some images on iPhone

Tags: ios, forms, css, recaptcha

I have a simple form that uses Google ReCaptcha v2 to verify.  Its working fine on desktop/ipad and iphone on all browsers I have tested so far.  The problem I have discovered is that when I click "I'm not a robot" on the smaller iphone screen in portrait mode - the images attempt to display below the form - and as the form is at the bottom of the page - it ends up cutting off like this:

[image: iPhone Portrait Mode]

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <p><b>CONTACT FORM</b>
  </p>
  <form role="form" id="form" action="form.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">

      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your name.</span>

      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>

      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>

      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="INSERT DATA SITE KEY HERE"></div>
      <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please check that you are not a robot.</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="Submit" data-loading-text="Sending..." class="btn btn-default">Send Message</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

When I rotate iPhone to landscape - it then displays the images above the reCaptcha widget which is good.  But rotate back to portrait it tries to display the pictures below the widget - and cuts off anything below the end of page - and inserts a big white space. Any ideas what I can do to resolve?